# Why is a cast required?

Tags: c#, c#-10.0

(.Net 6, c# 10)

Take a look at this code :

```
public class A {
   int Foo { get; set; }    
}

public interface IResponse : IEnumerable<A> {}



public class Program
{
    public static void Main() {
        var asList = new List<A>();

        IEnumerable<A> asEnumerable = asList;

        IResponse asResource = asEnumerable;
    }
}
```

The compiler complains on line `IResponse asResource = asEnumerable;` :

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<A>' to 'IResponse'. 
An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Is there a "clean" way of fixing this? Most of the time, explicit casts are used as a last resort and I fear that I'm missing something.

**EDIT:** Is it because the "IResource : IEnumerable" syntax tells the compiler that IResource is potentially "more" than just IEnumerable, therefore later in the code when trying to convert it cannot guarantee that the potential *other* interfaces extended by IResources are present in "just" an IEnumerable?

Maybe I got too used to TypeScript where the compiler checks that all the interfaces match all the time.

**EDIT 2 :** The reason to be for IResource is more or less to be an alias for a return type in several files. I know about the following trick :

```
using IResource = IEnumerable<A>;
```

but the problem with that is that I have to do it in every file. If you know of a better solution...

Comment: Just because a IResponse implements IEnumerable<A> doesn't mean that IEnumerable<A> is necessarily an IResponse.

Comment: You could make a member function of class A that returns itself cast to IResponse?

Comment: For example, if you have `class Cat : Animal`, you can be sure that a Cat is always an Animal. But you can't be sure that an Animal is always a Cat. A particular instance of an Animal *might* be a Cat, but it could also be a Dog or a Gorilla or any other type that implements or inherits from Animal.

Comment: @mason you are correct, I understood it by "rubber-duckie'ing" with myself. that's the first EDIT. Can you have a look at EDIT 2 ?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish with your 2nd edit. But this isn't the proper place to ask about it. It's unrelated to your original question.

Comment: @mason ok. You should post your first comment as the answer though, to get the points.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to alias a type globally for the entire project, use `using` directive with [`global` modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#global-modifier):

```cs
// In any file, do this once
global using IResource = IEnumerable<A>;
global using B = System.Collections.Generic.List<int>;
```

Then use it anywhere:

```cs
IResource  a = new List<string>();

B b = new();
Console.WriteLine(b.GetType().Name); // prints List`1
```

Comment: I'm in a  pickle because that was not my original question, however you're answering my secondary question; If I mark you as "accepted answer" then you'll get the points I'm supposed to give to @mason

Comment: @jeancallisti yeah next time either close this question and create another, or when you edit, edit the title as well please and modify the **main** question if the question somehow changes.

Comment: On Monday I will repost my secondary question and let you know, to be able to explore more with you or someone else. For now I will give the points to @mason if he posts his comment as an answer.